# Best practice in Rails when editing scaffold made pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

I have a best practice question. I have two classes, company and category. They have a many-to-many relationship. When clicking a category I shall go to a page showing all companies with the chosen category. Pretty straight forward.

My question is:

Should I list all the companies on the companies/index.html.erb after filtering the companies in the controller?

or

Should I list all the companies on the categories/show.html.erb page?

or

Should I do a completely new page, since it doesn't really fit into any of the two above?

Do you generally make a new page when your goal doesn't fit the scaffold made pages or do you use them quite freely?

I am working/learning alone with rails, so there are a lot of best practice questions popping up all the time.

Cheers Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scaffold is a starting point, so you should always consider what **you** need in your web application.

In you case, I think all examples are fine, but again, it's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just learning Rails, stick to as many conventions as possible.  Scaffolding is one of the ways Rails can help you get things started when you don't know how all of the pieces work together.

But like Oscar said, ultimately you must decide what your application will need.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby on Rails platform comes with many principles such as DRY etc. 
The main part is the MVC architecture, the thing scaffolding does is let you see how this MVC is used correctly by a Model, View and Controller generation.

When you learn how this works you will be able to answer your own question, I could write my thoughts down but it is key for a Rails developer to understand the MVC structure so my suggestion is to read:

```
http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/
```

have fun